# Scraping Linkedin with python only returns ''[ ]'

Tags: python, request, linkedin-api, lxml, data-extraction

I am trying to scrape LinkedIn to get the current and education elements(This information is publicly available) from any user profile. However, after running this code I cant get the information i need but instead only empty brackets [].

https://www.linkedin.com/in/bryan-engelhardt-a099204b This is the exact link i am using at this moment and from here i want to be able to scrape the following information: "Current-College of the Holy Cross" and "Education-University of Iowa"

My code is pretty simple:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/bryan-engelhardt-a099204b')
data = html.fromstring(response.text)

print(data.xpath('//title/text()')) #looks for title and prints it
print(data.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/ol/li/span/a/text()')) # using a direct xpath
print(data.xpath('//*[@id="topcard"]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ol/li/a/text()'))
```

The output looks as follows:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/Holy Cross - Summer/Desktop/python/scrape/scrape1.py"
[]
[]
[]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not sure why its returning that as an response as i have tried this with other websites and gotten successful results. It might be LinkedIn trying to block me from getting this information and if it is, how can i get around it.

Comment: Maybe start of by printing the response?

Comment: Printing response gives me <Response [999]>. I am assuming that linkedin is denying me access to thier information and thus returning [ ]. How do i get around that?

Comment: Did you read the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read linkedin terms of service.

The linkedin [robots.txt file](https://www.linkedin.com/robots.txt) states that you need whitelisting to scrape the site.

```
# Notice: If you would like to crawl LinkedIn,
# please email whitelistcrawl@linkedin.com to apply
# for white listing.
```

I would start by trying to apply for whitelisting.

You could try to make your bot look like a human by playing with the user agent and whatnot, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try. Also, by not logging in with an account I am not agreeing to their user agreements(which prohibit scraping), which then theoretically should freely let me scrape the information that is open to the public, but i guess not...

Comment: Sure, but they are also free not to let you in.